# Springdata mongodb aggregation match

Tags: spring, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

After asking question to understand a bit more of the aggregation framework in MongoDB I finally found the way to do aggregation for my need (thanks to a StackExchange user)

So basically here is a document from my collection:

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("s4dcsd5s4d6c54s6d"),
        "items" : [
            {
                type : "TYPE_1",
                text : "blablabla"
            },
            {
                type : "TYPE_2",
                text : "blablabla"
            },
            {
                type : "TYPE_3",
                text : "blablabla"
            },
            {
                type : "TYPE_1",
                text : "blablabla"
            },
            {
                type : "TYPE_2",
                text : "blablabla"
            },
            {
                type : "TYPE_1",
                text : "blablabla"
            }
        ]
        }
```

The idea was to be able to filter only some elements of my collections (avoiding Type 2 and 3). In fact I have more than 30 types and 6 are not allowed but for simplicity I made this example.
So the aggregation command in command line is this one:

```
    db.history.aggregate([{
             $match: {
                 _id: ObjectId("s4dcsd5s4d6c54s6d")
             }
         }, {
             $unwind: '$items'
         }, {
             $match: {
                 'items.type': { '$nin': [ "TYPE_2" , "TYPE_3"] }
             }
         },
         { $limit: 10 }
     ]);
```

With this I am able to retrieve the 10 elements items of this document which do not match `TYPE_2` and `TYPE_3`

However when I am using spring data there is no output. I looked a bit at the example to build mine but its still not working.

So I did:

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
    match(Criteria.where("id").is(myID)), 
    unwind("items"),
    match(Criteria.where("items.type").nin(ignoreditemstype)), 
    limit(3), 
    skip(offsetLong)
);

AggregationResults<PersonnalHistory> results = mongAccess.getOperation().aggregate(query,
            "items", PersonnalHistory.class);
```

`PersonnalHistory` is marked with annotation `@Document(collection = "history")` and id with the `@id` annotation

`ignoreditemstype` is a list containing `TYPE_2` and `TYPE_3`

Here is what I have in the `toString` method of aggregation:

```
{ 
    "aggregate" : "__collection__" , 
    "pipeline" : [ 
        { "$match": { "id" : "s4dcsd5s4d6c54s6d"} }, 
        { "$unwind": "$items"},
        { "$match": { "items.type": { "$nin" : [ "TYPE_2" , "TYPE_3" ] } } }, 
        { "$limit" : 3}, 
        { "$skip" : 0 }
    ]
}
```

I tried a lot of stuff (to have at least an answer :) ) like removing id or the nin:

```
aggregation = newAggregation(
    unwind("items"),
    match(Criteria.where("items.type").nin(ignoreditemstype)), 
    limit(3), 
    skip(offsetLong)
);

aggregation = newAggregation(
    match(Criteria.where("id").is(myid)), 
    unwind("items")
);
```

For information when I do a simple query like:

```
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("id").is(myID));
```

My document is returned. However I have thousands of items. So I just want to have the 15 first (in fact the 15 first are the 15 last added)

Do you maybe see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `AggregationResults<PersonnalHistory> results = mongAccess.getOperation().aggregate(query,
            "items", PersonnalHistory.class);` Shouldn't the second parameter be `history` and first parameter be `aggregation` ??

Comment: No because in fact it is the targetted class. So my PersonnalHistory is binded on the history collection...

Comment: its string right ?? how is that a targeted class ? If I understand correctly you are using this variant. `<O> AggregationResults<O> aggregate(Aggregation aggregation, String collectionName, Class<O> outputType);` which takes the second param as collection name.

Comment: Ah you are right. I will try this evening. If working i will let you know. So you will be able to put answer and i will put a plus 1. Thanks  :)

Comment: Men Your solution is working combined to the solution of the answer above :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah looks like you are passing simple String while it is expecting ObjectId

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
    match(Criteria.where("_id").is(new ObjectId(myID))), 
    unwind("items"),
    match(Criteria.where("items.type").nin(ignoreditemstype)), 
    limit(3), 
    skip(offsetLong)
);
```

Now the question is why it works with simple query, my answer would be because spring-data driver is not that mature at least not with aggregation pipeline.

Comment: What objectId do you use ?  I cannot find it in the javadoc of spring data. http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.9.6.RELEASE/api/

Comment: Oh! org.bson.types.ObjectId , I guess it is in mongo-java-driver https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.3.0

Comment: Thanks I will havr a look

Comment: You can still continue to use id as string, but you just have to use this variant `<O> AggregationResults<O> aggregate(Aggregation aggregation, Class<?> inputType, Class<O> outputType);` which will map the id to ObjectId behind the scene using typed aggregation. Notice the second arg which is input type which will where spring look for @Id annotation to do the mapping for `match(Criteria.where("id").is("idstring")`

Comment: Thanks it is working with the solution in the comment of my question.